# How do I sort a CSV file

Tags: csv, sorting, unix, awk, format

I would like to sort a CSV file by the 36th column skipping the first 8 rows.

I have tried:

```
awk '(NR>8 ){print; }' Hight_5x5.csv | sort -nk36
```

but it does not work.

I think it could probably due to the format of the data which has `","` separations. For example,  `...,"0.041","3.5","40","false","1000","1.3","20","5","5","-20","2","100000000","0.8",...` are some of the data in a single row.

My data files are in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ool5ab361ku19zc/AAB-p56TqHDAbAKGIiDNNfqNa?dl=0).

Regards

Comment: Adding a field separator with `-t` will take care of it (`sort -nk36 -t,`), but you have to be _sure_ that none of the first 35 fields themselves contain a `,`

Comment: @jas Thank you. I do not know how to use the `-t` option. I have tried `","` but does not work.

Comment: When you say it does not work, is it that you get an error? Or that the resulting output is not sorted as expected?

Comment: @jas The result is not sorted.

Comment: Can you try with a simple 3-line, 3-column file, e.g.: `a,3,c\nb,1,d\nc,2,e`. Then sort with `sort -nk2 -t, file`.  Is the file sorted by the second column?

Comment: @jas with a 3x3 data file separated by `,` it works but if I add commas to each number (the format of my csv file) then it does not work.

Comment: @jas Since I intend to pass the sorted CSV file to Gnuplot it is probably that I should remove first the commas of each number. Do you know how could I do it?

Comment: Okay, well done, at least we know what the problem is now. `sort` isn't smart enough to know which commas separate fields and which commas are part of a field.

Comment: It's probably time for a new question, then. Try to make it as much of an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as possible. Give an example file with just a few lines and just a few columns, making sure to include realistic data --- especially numbers with commas (note that none of the numbers in your sample data above contain commas!).  Good luck!!

Comment: @jas Thank you.